# Are DynamoDB connections encrypted by default?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

We would like to use DynamoDB database from an unsafe location, where internet traffic potentially may be sniffed. Does .NET library for DynamoDB encrypt the content it sends to the server?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [HTTPS DynamoDB endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ddb_region), your [requests to DynamoDB will be transported under HTTPS protocol](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Endpoints.html).

Comment: The problem is that in SDK we do not specify endpoint directly, but region instead, so we don't know which endpoint is used, ex: `(var client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonDynamoDBClient(RegionEndpoint.USEast1)) { ... }`